# iOS select versus kqueue/kevent versus mach_wait_until scheduling

Tags: ios, multithreading, sockets

I have a thread that listens on a single UDP socket, but also needs to wake up once in a while to perform other tasks.  These tasks are triggered by the passage of time, or by activity on other threads.  My current design is to use select() timeout value as scheduling timer, and to write a packet to the socket (loopback) address when I need to wake it from another thread.

However, Apple documention says select() timeouts should not be used to wake up more than a few times per second.  And, in practice, I find they may be delayed by 100 msec or more, whereas I would like 10-20 msec resolution.  Are they just trying to discourage cpu intensive polling, or is there something wrong with using select() per se.  Is there a better approach?

Would it help to replace select with kqueue/kevent?  Or, create a dedicated scheduling thread, with mach_wait_until() to handle the timer, and then write to the socket to wake the net thread?  Or, do all the work in the dedicated thread, and have the net thread queue incoming data to it?

Answer (score 0):

Something bugs me about this approach. Why do you have anything at all happening on the select() thread?

If you need a thread dedicated to waiting for incoming packets, them make that thread a wait as much as possible.

```
while (1) {
    int numsockets = select(…);
    if (numsockets > 0) {
        // Read data (only drain the socket)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            // Process data
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can have your periodic tasks run using [timer dispatch sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html).

```
dispatch_source_t source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0,
                                                  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source, ^{
    // Periodic process data
});

uint64_t nsec = 0.001 * NSEC_PER_SEC;
dispatch_source_set_timer(source, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, nsec), nsec, 0);
dispatch_resume(source);
```

---

I don't know, but I've been told that you can even use a dispatch source to replace the select().

Comment: Essentially, the operations related to packet IO need to be serialized on a single thread.  It seems more efficient to queue these operations to the thread that is doing the read, since the operations will often be triggered by a read anyway, so no context switch required.  Your approach would seem to require 2 thread context switches on every read, one where the select() wakes up and a second on the dispatch queue.  My sense of the Apple recommendations is they simply want to minimize context switches, not that there is any problem with waking up from select, if someone has got to wake

Comment: I understand your concern, but I think it may be a case of premature optimization. Using `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` will ensure the block is dispatched on an often used queue. The context switch will be a sunk cost because there will be other blocks running on the same queue. If you go all in and use a dispatch source to replace the select(), then it will be assigned to the same queue eliminating your `select()` thread altogether.

Comment: I think if a thread is already running and can finish the work itself, it would seldom make sense to dispatch the work to a different thread.  That seems like premature complication not premature optimization :-).  Where your design makes sense to me is if the work might take too long, or block on other system resources, letting data pile up in the socket.  I do have that sort of work sometimes, but that is the point that I queue it to a different thread, after updating the state necessary to manage packet protocol.